# DAX: Summarizing generated table in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to use the following DAX formula as a calculated table:

```
FailingTable = 
SUMMARIZE(    
        ADDCOLUMNS(GENERATESERIES(1 , 100),
        "Group", [Value],    
        "ValueToSum", RAND()        
        )
,
[Group], "Total", SUM([ValueToSum])
)
```

It says Cannot identitfy the table that contains ValueToSum.
The same happens if i use a GENERATE to crossjoin the series to a table.

Why do this not work? And how could i make it work?

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to achieve. Why are you trying to summarize a generated series, where each value is already distinct? Won't this simply work: `MyTable = ADDCOLUMNS ( GENERATESERIES ( 1, 100 ), "Total", RAND() )`

Comment: This is a condensed example showing my problem. I'm trying to implement a simple monte carlo simulation in DAX, without using R or Python. This means i use GENERATESERIES to generate the trials and then crossjoin these on to my cases and then SUM them up.